# How to extract some specific string from url?

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

Using PHP function or Php regex, how can I extract only 568429042356.html or 568429042356 from the link below?

https://sub.example.com/offer/568429042356.html?spm=b2611038.mof001.21.10393eccdCb5XA&sk=consign

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to extract the path part of the URL, and then [`basename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to get the filename from that:

```
$url = 'https://sub.example.com/offer/568429042356.html?spm=b2611038.mof001.21.10393eccdCb5XA&sk=consign';
echo basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Output:

```
568429042356.html
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/QVMC6)